# Is it possible to display the save/cancel buttons in Vaadin 14 on GridPro when editing the grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

In Vaadin 8's grid you would see the Save/Cancel button when doubleclicking on a row in `GridPro`. In Vaadin 14 Grid Pro doesn't seem to have that save save/cancel button by default. Is there a way to enable it?

It seems like it should be possible because we have `getEditor().addSaveListener()` etc.

As an extra question whenever I do any action in the grid it seems to only call the `addCancelListener()`. Is there a reason for this? The primary question of course is if it's possible to show the save/cancel buttons in `GridPro`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GridPro` adds another editing functionality to the `Grid`, which is not using `grid.getEditor()` at all. So these are not to be mixed.

`GridPro` is designed for cell-based spreadsheet like editing with improved keyboard navigation, thus save/cancel buttons are not there. Editable columns are added using grid.addEditColumn(..) method and using either built in fields like below, or custom type. In both cases saving of the value is handled in the call back provided.

```
grid.addEditColumn(Person::getEmail)
        .text((item, newValue) ->
                item.setEmail(newValue))
        .setHeader("Email (editable)");
```

So save / cancel events from grid's editor are not emitted. Also this functionality does not use `Binder` by default. You need wire Binder yourself if you need it, see example in [Vaadin's cookbook](https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-pro-binder).

Basic `Grid` has builtin row based editor, which uses also `Binder`. With that one you can use it Binder and editor in buffered mode, and for example add an additional component column to where you have edit / cancel buttons, what ever you like. There is rather good code example at [Vaadin's component pages](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/grid-editor).

In summary there are two different editing facilities provided and these are not to be mixed.